# Scanner skips line in text file and doesn't print leading whitespace

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I want to read in a text file and print the responses in my Java program.

My text file contains a number of lines, each containing a string of grades. Some of them have leading whitespace (indicating blanks).

I'm having two problems:
1. the first line in the text file isn't printing; it starts from the 2nd line
2. one of the grade lines contains two "spaces" at the beginning indicating blanks; those blank spaces are not printing.

Below is my code. Any input into how I can fix this? New programmer here so really appreciate your help.

```
public static void printResponses (File f) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner (f);
      String line;
      int count = 1;

      while (input.nextLine() != null)
      {
         line = input.nextLine();
         System.out.println ("Student #" + count +"\'s responses: " + line);
         count++;
      }  
      System.out.println ("We have reached \"end of file!\"\n");  

      if (!f.exists())
      {
         System.out.println ("An error occurred. Please try again.");
         System.exit(0);
      }                                                             
   }
```

Comment: Notice how you read two lines in your `while` loop.

Comment: `Scanner` class has `hasNextLine()` method.

Comment: Also, `nextLine` never returns `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call `input.nextLine()` you're consuming a 'token' from the input file. That is, the `Scanner` `input` goes through the input you've provided and 'uses up' a line as it scans it.

When you call `while (input.nextLine() != null)` you're consuming the first line of the file.

You want to call `while (input.hasNextLine())` so you don't consume a token without using it at the beginning of each loop iteration.